# Android metadata from manifest returning null

Tags: android, metadata, android-applicationinfo

I have a class with one method that tries to retrieve meta-data from the manifest. Everything works fine except that the bundle that I create from the application info returns null values

Here's the code:

```
    private int getCurrentVersion(){
    int currVersion = 0;

    try {
        ApplicationInfo app = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        Bundle bundle = app.metaData;

        for (String key: bundle.keySet())
        {
          Log.d ("TEST", key + " is a key in the bundle");
        }

        Log.d("TEST","google: "+bundle.getString("com.google.android.gms.version"));
        Log.d("TEST","version: "+bundle.getString("dbVersion"));

        //currVersion = Integer.valueOf(bundle.getString("dbVersion"));
        currVersion = 1;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();         
    }

    return currVersion;
}


03-05 18:53:23.818: D/TEST(31400): com.google.android.gms.version is a key in the bundle
03-05 18:53:23.818: D/TEST(31400): dbVersion is a key in the bundle
03-05 18:53:23.828: D/TEST(31400): google: null
03-05 18:53:23.828: D/TEST(31400): version: null
```

As you can see I'm using some logs to see if the bundle is empty, but its not.

Comment: It looks like whatever they are, they aren't Strings. Is it possible you're providing a value like "1" and that it's being interpreted as the int 1?

Comment: for future readers, make sure you've put <meta-data> under <application> tag. Not under <manifest> tag.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In some cases you need to use `getInt()` method:

```
bundle.getInt("com.google.android.gms.version"));
```

because the value of this meta-data is defined as an integer.

```
Log.d("TEST","google: "+bundle.getInt("com.google.android.gms.version"));
```

For example if the value defined in your meta-data is a String:

```
     <meta-data 
         android:name="com.elenasys.a"
         android:value="abcXJ434" />
```

use:

```
   bundle.getString("com.elenasys.a"));
```

if the value is an integer:

```
   <meta-data 
         android:name="com.elenasys.b"
         android:value="1234" />
```

use `getInt()`

```
 bundle.getInt("com.elenasys.b"));
```

Comment: Oh I get it now. meta-data is a string type but it seems to be converted to int when I get the bundle from the app.metaData right? I can't believe I didn't notice. Thank you!

Comment: I added android:value="true" and was trying with getString method when I should have used getBoolean. In my case getString was causing the error.

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure the tag is under the manifest/application node in AndroidManifest.xml and not just under the root:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.readmetadata"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <meta-data android:name="dbVersion" android:value="1.0" />

        <activity android:name=".MainMenu" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: This did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot ! 1 hour or more left to find you :)